# image cache header issues

Tags: android, image, cache-control

I have a question about cache images in android. We generate images with max-age = 1 day and they stores into android devcies. But if we make make changes in image e.g then android device not picks the changed image till 1 day expiry. How can we make sure that if image is changed within max-age span it should fetch the new one.

Any idea ?

Comment: Using [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Comment: etag is in image headers. and it appear different when i change the image at server side but in andriod device it is picking max-age and not loading new image.